# Unable to install Pandas, I get multiple errors

Tags: pandas

I get errors when I try to install pandas in Windows 10, several errors the last one is in red:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-07bztlx0\pandas\
```

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 0):

**try with:**

In python executable file-

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","pandas"])
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. I also formatted the PC and installed WIndows 7 instead, tried again, same errror